# Is this approximation for $\pi$ enough to make this value converge? And how to find an upper bound for it

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, upper-bounds

Update:
\begin{align*}
|I_n-J_n| = (\pi-S_n)\sum_{k=0}^n |\frac{a_kp_k(\ln\pi)}{\ln^{k+1}\pi}|
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
|I_n| = \sum_{k=0}^n | \frac{a_k\pi p_k(\ln\pi)}{\ln^{k+1}\pi} 
 -\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a_kk!}{\ln^{k+1}\pi}| \leq
 |\sum_{k=0}^n  \frac{a_k\pi p_k(\ln\pi)}{\ln^{k+1}\pi} |
 + |\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a_kk!}{\ln^{k+1}\pi}|\\ \implies
- |\sum_{k=0}^n  \frac{a_k\pi p_k(\ln\pi)}{\ln^{k+1}\pi} | \leq
 |\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a_kk!}{\ln^{k+1}\pi}| -|I_n| \\\implies
|I_n-J_n| = (S_n-\pi)\sum_{k=0}^n -|\frac{a_kp_k(\ln\pi)}{\ln^{k+1}\pi}|\\
\leq (S_n-\pi)\left(|\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a_kk!}{\ln^{k+1}\pi}|-|I_n|\right)
\end{align*}
where I believe the $a_k$'s are the coeffcients of the [shifted legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Shifted_Legendre_polynomials). I believe $a_k<k!$ for every non negative $k$ because since $I_n= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\ln^{k+1}(\pi)} ( \pi p_k(\ln\pi) - k! )$ goes to $0$ as $n$ grows larger, that means that $( \pi p_k(\ln\pi) - k! )$ goes to $0$ (in a factorial rate) faster than $a_k$'s goes to infinity, as $n$ grows larger.

**Question**

I asked this in another forum but hoping someone will help me here.

For some positive integer $n$, define $I_n$ as
\begin{align}
I_n&=\int_0^1  \frac{(x-x^2)^n}{n!} \pi^x\ln^n\pi dx \\
\end{align}
this integral has the following form
\begin{align*}
I_n&=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\ln^{k+1}(\pi)} ( \pi p_k(\ln\pi) - k! ) \tag{1}
\end{align*}
where $a_k$ are integers and $p_k(\ln\pi)$ are polynomials with degree $k$ evaluated at $\ln\pi$.

This integral is positive and will always converge, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}I_n=0$. Notice that $\pi$ is present in expression $(1)$. (I'm not talking about $\pi$ inside the $\ln$ but rather the factor the multiplies $p_k$). What will happen if we change this $\pi$ to an approximation of it? Consider the expression,
\begin{align*}
J_n&=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\ln^{k+1}(\pi)} ( S_n p_k(\ln\pi) - k! )
\end{align*}
where $S_n$ is a truncated series such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\pi$. For example, consider the truncated BBP formula
\begin{align*}
S_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{f(n)}\left( \frac{4}{16^k(8k+1)}
-\frac{2}{16^k(8k+4)}
-\frac{1}{16^k(8k+5)}
-\frac{1}{16^k(8k+6)}\right)
\end{align*}
where $f(n)$ is some function in $n$ such that the following must be true
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{16^{f(n)}e^{8f(n)}}{n!}=0. \tag{2}
\end{align*}

I noticed that if we choose a bad $f(n)$ such as $f(n)=n$, our $S_n$ will approximate $\pi$ very slowly, and $J_n$ will diverge to infinity or negative infinity as $n$ grows larger. For example, with $f(100)=100$ we must only iterate the BBP formula $100$ times giving a bad approximation to $\pi$ which results in  the large difference between $I_{100}=7.7472...\cdot  10^{-241}$ and $J_{100}=-3.2990\cdot 10^{84}$.

However, if we choose $f(n)=\lfloor n(\ln n)^{0.99}\rfloor$ the limit $(2)$ will be true (I used SageMath to evaluate this), and it gives a much better approximation. For example, now $f(100)=453$, and iterating the BBP formula $453$ times, gives a better approximation for $\pi$ and now $J_{100}=7.7472...\cdot10^{-241}$ has $75$ correct digits when comparing with $I_{100}$.

With this $f(n)=\lfloor n(\ln n)^{0.99}\rfloor$ will the truncated BBP formula always produce an approximation of $\pi$ good enough so that $\lim_{n\to\infty}J_n=0$ ? And how close it is from $I_n$ ? In the end of this post there is an upper bound for $I_n$. I need an upper bound for $J_n$. If this $f(n)$ is not good enough, there exists a $f(n)$ respecting $(2)$ that will make $J_n$ always converge when $n$ goes to infinity?

**Example: Consider $n=2$**
\begin{align}
I_2&= (12 (-1 + π) - 6 (1 + π) \log(π) + (-1 + π) \log^2(π))/(\log^3(π)) \approx 0.0396.
\end{align}
To find $J_2$ we must find $S_2$:
\begin{align*}
S_{2}=\sum_{k=0}^{f(2)}\left( \frac{4}{16^k(8k+1)}
-\frac{2}{16^k(8k+4)}
-\frac{1}{16^k(8k+5)}
-\frac{1}{16^k(8k+6)}\right)
\end{align*}
where $f(2)=1$, which gives the following approximation for $\pi$:  $S_2=102913/32760.$ Therefore we have,
\begin{align}
J_2&= (12 (-1 + 102913/32760) - 6 (1 + 102913/32760) \log(π) + (-1 + 102913/32760) \log^2(π))/(\log^3(π)) \approx 0.0388.
\end{align}

**More information:**

For some $b>0$,
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 x^n b^x  dx = \int_0^1 x^n e^{\ln(b) x} dx = \frac{1}{\ln^{n+1}(b)} \int_0^{\ln(b)} x^n e^x dx.
\end{align*}
Let's change $x^n$ for a polynomial $P_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$,
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 P_n(x) b^x  dx = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\ln^{k+1}(b)} \int_0^{\ln(b)} x^k e^x  dx
\end{align*}
where $\int x^ke^xdx$ has the shape $e^xp_k(x)$ where $p_k(x)$ is a polynomial with degree $k$ and has integer coefficients. The independent coefficient is $k!$.  Integrating from $0$ to $\ln b$ we have $\int_0^{\ln b} x^ke^xdx=e^{\ln b} p_k(\ln b)-e^0p_k(0) = bp_k(\ln b)-k!$.
Take $b=\pi$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
I_n&=\int_0^1 P_n(x) \pi^x  dx = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\ln^{k+1}(\pi)} \int_0^{\ln(\pi)} x^k e^x  dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\ln^{k+1}(\pi)} ( \pi p_k(\ln\pi) - k! ).
\end{align*}
Denote the above integral by $I_n$, where $P_n(x)$ is the following polynomial
\begin{align*}
P_n(x)=\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \frac{(x-x^2)^n}{n!}.
\end{align*}
We can integrate by parts $n$ times $I_n$ using the following rule
\begin{align*}
\int_a^b \frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)g(x)dx=(-1)^n\int_a^b 
f(x)\frac{d^n}{dx^n}g(x)dx
\end{align*}
if $f(a)g(a)=f(b)g(b)=0.$

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \frac{(x-x^2)^n}{n!} \pi^x dx &=(-1)^n \int_0^1  \frac{(x-x^2)^n}{n!}
\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \pi^xdx \\
&=(-1)^n\int_0^1  \frac{(x-x^2)^n}{n!} \pi^x\ln^n\pi dx.
\end{align*}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
|I_n|&=\int_0^1  \frac{(x-x^2)^n}{n!} \pi^x\ln^n\pi dx \\
&\leq\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^1 [max(x-x^2)]^n \pi^x \ln^n\pi dx \\
&=\frac{1}{n!} (1/4)^n \ln^n\pi \int_0^1\pi^xdx \\
&= \frac{1}{n!} (1/4)^n \ln^n\pi \frac{\pi-1}{\ln\pi}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Can you link to the other forum where you asked about this? And put a link there to your question here?

Comment: For each nonnegative integer $n$ we have 
$$I_n-J_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\ln^{k+1}(\pi)} ( \pi p_k(\ln\pi) - k! )-\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\ln^{k+1}(\pi)} ( S_n p_k(\ln\pi) - k! )=$$
$$(\pi-S_n)\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\ln^{k+1}(\pi)}p_k(\ln\pi).$$
Thus I think to answer your questions we have to estimate the latter value, so we need to have upper bounds for $|a_k|$'s and $|p_k(x)|$'s, at $x=\ln\pi$.
Can you provide these bounds?

Comment: @AlexRavsky I think the $a_k$'s are the coefficients of the shifted legendre polynomials. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Shifted_Legendre_polynomials

Comment: I guess some signs "$=$" in the update should be replaced by "$\le$", and "$\pi-S_n$" by "$|\pi-S_n|$".

Comment: I say, CAN YOU LINK TO THE OTHER FORUM WHERE YOU ASKED ABOUT THIS?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I posted here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4778123/with-this-approximation-of-pi-will-this-value-converge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each nonnegative integer $n$ we have
$$I_n-J_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\ln^{k+1}(\pi)} ( \pi p_k(\ln\pi) - k! )-\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\ln^{k+1}(\pi)} ( S_n p_k(\ln\pi) - k! )=$$
$$(\pi-S_n)\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\ln^{k+1}(\pi)}p_k(\ln\pi).$$

As far as I see, $P_n(x)$ from the question equals $\widetilde P_n(x)$ from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Shifted_Legendre_polynomials). Next, as I see, $e^xp_k(x)=\int_{0}^{x} y^ke^y dy+p_k(0)$ (by the way, in the question is written that $p_k(0)=k!$, whereas Mathcad calculations suggest that $p_k(0)=(-1)^kk!$; for instance, I obtained $\int x^3e^x dx=(x^3-3x^2-6x-6)e^x+C$ and  $\int x^4e^x dx=(x^4-4x^3+12x^2-24x+24)e^x+C$).

Thus we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\ln^{k+1} \pi}p_k(\ln\pi)=$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\ln^{k+1} \pi}e^{-\ln\pi}\left(\int_{0}^{\ln\pi} y^ke^y dy+p_k(0)\right)=$$
$$e^{-\ln\pi}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\ln^{k+1} \pi}\int_{0}^{\ln\pi} y^ke^y dy+e^{-\ln\pi}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\ln^{k+1} \pi}p_k(0)=$$
$$\frac 1\pi I_n+\frac 1\pi\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\ln^{k+1} \pi}p_k(0).$$

Then
$$I_n-J_n=\left(1-\frac{S_n}{\pi}\right)\left(I_n+\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\ln^{k+1} \pi}p_k(0)\right).$$

Thus we have to bound the absolute value of $T_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\ln^{k+1} \pi}p_k(0)$. I assume that $p_k(0)=(-1)^kk!$.
Then
$$T_n=
(-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^n \frac 1{\ln^{k+1} \pi}\cdot {n\choose k}{n+k\choose k}k!=$$
$$(-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^n \frac 1{\ln^{k+1} \pi}\cdot \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}\cdot\frac{(n+k)!}{n!k!}\cdot k!=$$
$$(-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^n \frac 1{\ln^{k+1} \pi}\cdot \frac{(n+k)!}{(n-k)!k!}.$$

A rather rough estimation is $(n+k)!\le (2n)!$ for each nonegative integer $k\le n$.
Thus

$$|T_n|\le \sum_{k=0}^n \frac 1{\ln^{k+1} \pi}\cdot \frac{(2n)!}{(n-k)!k!}=$$
$$\frac{(2n)!}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac 1{\ln^{k+1} \pi}\cdot \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!\ln\pi}\left(1+\frac 1{\ln\pi}\right)^n.$$

Unfortunately, I expect that we cannot compensate the growth even of the last summand $(-1)^n\frac 1{\ln^{n+1} \pi}\cdot \frac{(2n)!}{0!n!}$ for $T_n$ of this bound by suitable choice of $f(n)$. Indeed, approximating $|S_n-\pi|$ by the last summand $$\frac{4}{16^k(8k+1)}
-\frac{2}{16^k(8k+4)}
-\frac{1}{16^k(8k+5)}
-\frac{1}{16^k(8k+6)}$$
in the sum for $S_n$, we obtain that
$$|S_n-\pi|\approx \frac{120k^2+151k+47}{(8k+1)(8k+4)(8k+5)(8k+6)}\approx \frac{15}{64}16^{-k}k^{-2},$$
where $k=f(n)$. This value should compensate the value $$\frac 1{\ln^{n+1} \pi}\cdot \frac{(2n)!}{0!n!}.$$
Neglecting the factors of the smaller growth, we obtain that $16^{f(n)}\ge\approx \frac{(2n)!}{n!}$.
But then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{16^{f(n)}e^{8f(n)}}{n!}\ge\approx e^{8f(n)}\frac{(2n!)}{n!^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{8f(n)}{2n\choose n}=\infty,$$ which violates $(2)$.